# Use SpringAOP to intercept send and receive messages

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

For some reasons, I have to intercept send and receive messages. (Wrap up the message and parse the message when it is received).

I know `MessagePostProcessor` is a form of interceptor, but it will influence current code. So, I am considering using Spring AOP.

For sending messages, I can simply intercept RabbitTemplate’s `send` and `convertAndSend` methods, Like the following code：

```
@Around("execution(* org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(..))")
```

But for receiving messages, Which method is best to intercept? In most cases, `RabbitListener` is used to receive messages.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `Advice` to the listener container's `adviceChain`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#containerAttributes

**EDIT**

```java
@Bean
public MethodInterceptor advice() {
    return invocation -> {
        Message message = (Message) invocation.getArguments()[0];
        try {
            // before
            invocation.proceed();
            // after
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // ...
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            // ...
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to directly cut into a method that will definitely pass through？Such as `MessageingMessageListenerAdapter#onMessage`.

Comment: You don't need a point cut; the container wraps the `MessageListener.onMessage()` calls; just add a `MethodInterceptor` to the advice chain; see the edit. If you want to advise the adapter's delegate instead, then wrap it in a proxy.

Comment: Thanks！By the way, I am using `AmqpTemplate#addBeforePublishPostProcessors` to intercept send message, is there any way to get the routingkey, exchange when intercepting send messages? It seems that `MessagePostProcessor` only provides the two parameters :`Message` and `Correlation`.

Comment: Not currently; but it would not be hard to add such a feature. Please open an issue on GitHub. In the meantime, you can subclass the template, set the exchange/routing key in `messagePropeties.headers` (and remove them in the MPP).